# Python interaction in Pandas documentation

Tags: pandas

In this document http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/pandas.pdf the python interaction is done very nicely.
Where are the latex sources so I can see how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

The docs are generated using [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/).

You can see how by reading at the [`make.py`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/doc/make.py) file from the [pandas github repository](https://github.com/pydata/pandas).

Comment: I think that's how they did the API reference but not the pdf I linked to.
In the linked pdf file they have text along with code examples, that's what I search for.
Or did they also do this with sphinx?